Euclid’s “Elements” Redux Callahan's Problem 4
I'm working through Euclid's “Elements” Redux by Callahan (The 13 June 2024 edition), but I have a problem demonstrating the exercise. This time is one on page 107, specifically the number 9. The problem says:


If  $\overline {AC}$ and $\overline {BK}$ intersect at $P$ and a segment is constructed through P which is
parallel to $\overline{BC}$, meeting $\overline{AB}$ at $Q$, then $\overline{CP}=\overline{PQ}$. 


I wrote the following proof, but I can identify how it is still incomplete.
I use the following propositions to carry out the mathematical proof.

[1.29, Cor 1, pp. 78 ] EQUIVALENT STATEMENTS REGARDING PARALLEL LINES
If a line intersects a pair of lines, then the pair of lines are
parallel if and only if any of these three properties  hold:

corresponding alternate angles are equal;
exterior angles equal their corresponding interior angles;
the sum of the interior angles on the same side are equal to two right angles.



[1.34, pp. 85 ] OPPOSITE SIDES AND OPPOSITE ANGLES OF PARALELOGRAMS
Opposite sides and opposite angles of paralelogram are equal to one another and either diagonal bisects the parallelogram.


[1.37, pp. 91 ] TRIANGLES OF EQUAL AREA I
Triangles which stand on the same base and in the same parallels are equal in area

My proof goes like this:

Consider $△CPQ$ and $△NPO$. By [1.34], $△CPQ=△NPO$.
By [1.37], $△CPQ=△CPR$ and $△NPO=△BPQ$.
By [1.29, Cor 1], $∠KAB=∠PQB$, $∠BKA=∠BPQ$, $∠CAG=∠CPR$ and $∠AGC=∠PRC$.
Since $∠CPR=PQB$, $∠PRC=∠QBP$ $∠RCP=∠BPQ$ and $△CPR=△BPQ$, it follows that $△CPR≅△BPQ$.So $\overline{CP}=\overline{PQ}$

My first error is assuming that $\overline{PR}$, $\overline{CR}$ and $\overline{NR}$ are concurrent without making any demonstration of that and also that $\overline{PR}∥\overline{AG}$. Then, in the end, I don't have any preposition that says that two triangles with all the angles equal, but with the same area, are congruent. I don't know how to complete my proof, or even if there is a more direct demonstration.
Sorry, if my English is bad.

Are we assuming also that KA and AC are two sides of a squares/

@fleablood yes this is John Casey’s Elements put online, this is the usual I.47 diagram for Pythagorean theorem proof

Since $\triangle{PCB} \sim \triangle{PAK}$ we have $\frac{PC}{PA}=\frac{BC}{AK}=\frac{a}{b}$.
But since $\triangle{APQ} \sim \triangle{ACB}$ we have $\frac{PQ}{PA}=\frac{CB}{CA}=\frac{a}{b}$.
So $\frac{PC}{PA}=\frac{PQ}{PA}=\frac{a}{b}$. So $PC=PQ$.
Edit: Ah, I see your comment, doing it with hands tied behind the back, didn't realize. In that case we can do some apex sliding instead to stylistically mimic what Euclid does in his Pythagorean proof. Note that bases $CH, CA$ are equal by definition, and if we show $\triangle{CHP}=\triangle{CAQ}$ then we have our result since the altitudes $CP,PQ$ must then be equal.

$\triangle{KAB}=\frac{1}{2}KC=\triangle{KAP}+\triangle{HCP} \rightarrow \triangle{APB}=\triangle{HCP}$
because $\triangle{PBQ}=\triangle{PCQ}$, $\triangle{APB}=\triangle{ACQ}$
but then $\triangle{HCP}=\triangle{ACQ}$

We are done!

Tanks for the answer! I get your proof, but unfortunately I I'm not permitted to use that kind of proofs yet which are related to ratios of triangles of different area and derived from thales' theorem.

I have done only one similar exercise and, the only one mentioned, is this one in which two triangles of the same base or equal bases and between the same parallels, if these are cut by another parallel, the segment between the intersections of each triangle measures the same. To use that preposition I need to construct the triangles outside the original figure and prove that their base measures the same and lie between the same parallel to say that the segments measure the same.

Thanks a lot!. Totally understood. You have saved me.
